# Bulk Rename Photos

Tags: powershell

I have hundreds of Pics like named as 400110 front.jpg and 400110 side.jpg
needs to be renamed as  400110_1.jpg and 400110_2.jpg and 400110_3.jpg etc etc.

I am trying

```
foreach($picture in (get-childitem d:\test)){
    Rename-Item $picture.fullname 
    -NewName (($picture.name -replace " ", "_") +$count+$picture.Extension)
```

No luck, any guidance?

Comment: What is `<#BT#>` meant to be? _No luck, any guidance?_ What do you mean by no lucky? Is there an exception? Does your computer start smoking?

Comment: Does your code look *exactly* like what you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$N = 1
foreach($Picture in (get-childitem d:\test)){
    Rename-Item $Picture.FullName -NewName ($Picture.Name -replace ' front| side',"_$N")
    $N++
}
```

If in all files there is space after '400110'

'400110 front.jpg'

'400110 side.jpg'

'400110 mirror.jpg'

```
$N = 1
foreach($Picture in (get-childitem 'D:\test')){
    Rename-Item $Picture.FullName -NewName ($Picture.Name -replace " .*(\..*)","_$N`$1")
    $N++
}
```

Comment: Thanks,what about side you just replace font? there are many labels such as font,side,mirro

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: You know you are awesome